# SQLException when inserting data into DB

Tags: java, database, parameter-passing, prepared-statement, sqlexception

I am trying to insert data but its giving me success message but not inserted to database.I am using netbeans and Xampp. I tried many ways but it always the same.

This is my code:

```
public AddSeat() {
        initComponents();
        connect();
    }
    
Connection con;
PreparedStatement pst;

public void connect(){
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/busticket", "root", "");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(AddSeat.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(AddSeat.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

This is the insert method:

```
private void button2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    String busno = txtbus.getSelectedItem().toString();
    
    SimpleDateFormat Date_Format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/mm/dd");
    
    String date = Date_Format.format(txtdate.getDate());
    
    for(int i = 0; i<=30; i++)
    {
        try {
            int seats = i;
            String status = "Unbooked";
            pst = con.prepareStatement("insert into sat(busno, seats, date, status,) values(?, ? , '?' , '?')");
            pst.setString(1, busno);
            pst.setInt(2, seats);
            pst.setString(3, date);
            pst.setString(4, status);
            pst.executeUpdate();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(AddSeat.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Seat Added!");
}
```

The code is throwing this exception:

```
Jul 12, 2020 1:30:37 PM PracticePackage.AddSeat button2ActionPerformed
SEVERE: null
java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (3 > number of parameters, which is 2).
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:965)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:898)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:887)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:861)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.checkBounds(PreparedStatement.java:3385)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.setInternal(PreparedStatement.java:3370)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.setString(PreparedStatement.java:4095)
    at PracticePackage.AddSeat.button2ActionPerformed(AddSeat.java:206)
    at PracticePackage.AddSeat.access$200(AddSeat.java:20)
    at PracticePackage.AddSeat$3.actionPerformed(AddSeat.java:120)
    at java.awt.Button.processActionEvent(Button.java:409)
    at java.awt.Button.processEvent(Button.java:377)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Why is the code getting this error?

Comment: Don’t put the question marks in quotes. It doesn’t think they’re parameters that way.

Comment: Use **relevant** tags. Debug the DB side of it in a command line app. and don't add the [tag:swing] tag.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). Also don’t transfer the date as a string to your database, transfer a `LocalDate` using `pst.setObject(3, yourLocalDate);`.

Comment: No matter if using the modern `DateTimeFormatter` or the old and troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` beware of the case of format pattern letters. Please check the difference between lower case `mm` and upper case `MM` in a format pattern string.

Comment: The problem, as pointed out, is that you have put the question marks in quotations, so you're inserting literal question marks, but then because the code is seeing them as literal question marks it is no longer expecting four arguments, hence the error.  In general when posting to Stack Overflow you should include the detail of the actual exception (i.e. "Parameter index out of range (3 > number of parameters, which is 2).")  in your title to help people identify it.  Or perhaps even search for that first, which might have found you the answer faster.

Answer (score 1):

You are not supposed to surround ? with single quotes in your sql statement because then they get treated as a character and not a placeholder.

Change it to

```
prepareStatement("insert into sat(busno, seats, date, status,) values(?, ?, ?, ?)");
```

Comment: I removed the single quotes but still facing the same problem cant insert the data into the database

Comment: I doubt you are getting the same exception since this was clearly the issue. If you have another error now then you need to post a new question

Answer (score 1):

In prepared statement you don't have to quote the question marks, based on the type `set*` method will take of it.

```
pst = con.prepareStatement("insert into sat(busno, seats, date, status,) values(?, ?, ?, ?)");
```

Comment: Please don’t post duplicate answers

Comment: Still getting the same error and cant insert data into the database